# How to center text in table cell when it overflow?

Tags: html, css

I would like to center some text in the middle of my cell but the text is bigger than the width of the cell so it overflow to the right.

Would it be possible to make it overflow from the left and the right equally?

Here is a JSFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/p5wg8yyc/2/

The html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Left</th>
            <th>Center</th>
            <th>Right</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>SomeVeryBigTextThatDoesNotFit</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The CSS

```
table, td{
    border:1px solid black;
}

table{
    width:500px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

td{
    text-align:center;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: You're probably going to need JavaScript for that.

Comment: Remove the fixed layout?

Comment: And what will happen if you have text in the left and right td? They will go over it and that is not good :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's a CSS only way and it's very simple:

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/p5wg8yyc/9/

```
.toCenter {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Very nice! I tried to accomplish with positioning but didn't even consider using translation. Plus positioning ended up collapsing the table cell. Well done.

Comment: Does not work in IE8 and require -ms-transform for IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Simple css fix : http://jsfiddle.net/p5wg8yyc/8/

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td><span>AB</span></td>
    <td><span>SomeVeryBigTextThatDoesNotFit</span></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
td span{
    margin-left:-50%;
    margin-right:-50%;    
}
```

Comment: This fails in centering when the text is large and has line breaks: http://jsfiddle.net/p5wg8yyc/10/

Comment: Not if you add `display:inline-block`;

Comment: Works better when you replace the div by span.

Comment: Replace which div? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Left here for posterity, but Arbel's CSS-only answer is a much better approach.

---

Some JavaScript is probably required to make this happen. I've posted an example here using jQuery 1.11 which really just helps with selecting the elements and getting/setting their properties:

http://jsfiddle.net/sd8xw5d6/1/

Basically just getting the width of the cell and the text and adjusting the positioning:

```
$(function() {
    var textWidth = $(".overflowtext").width();
    var tdWidth = $(".overflowcell").width();
    $(".overflowtext").css("margin-left", tdWidth/2 - textWidth/2);
});
```

Note that while this works, you'd still need to account for window resizes and adjust as necessary, as the sizing will only work for the original window size, but hopefully this will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need

```css
           table, td{
    border:1px solid black;
}

table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:500px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

td{
    word-wrap:break-word;
    text-align:center;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
       <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Left</th>
            <th>Center</th>
            <th>Right</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>SomeVeryBigTextThatDoesNotFit</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The OP wants the text to overflow from left and right equally, not contain it in the cell.

Comment: Agreed, @Arbel's answer is on point, but I would also suggest that OP review this answer in case it's a better fit for his situation (I prefer this usability).