# Is it possible to have a DIV overflow both left and right when wider than its container?

Tags: html, css

I have a series of DIVs that are contained within a larger DIV. The container DIV is tall and narrow, so all the child DIVs are positioned in a single vertical column.

All of the child DIVs vary in width, and the margin declaration for all child divs is `margin: 0 auto 2em auto;`, so that when a child DIV is not as wide as the container, it it sits in the horizontal center. But when a child DIV is wider than the container DIV, the left edge of the child sits flush with the left edge of the container, and the right edge of the child expands past the right edge of the container.

Is it possible to instead make it so that when a child is wider than the parent DIV, it expands equally past both the right and left edges of the container so that it is visually centered?

Here is my current CSS:

```
.parent {
    margin: 2em auto;
    width:80%;
    border: red thin solid;
}
.child {
    border: green 3px solid;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    line-height:0;
    margin: 0 auto 2em auto;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like Javascript will be the easiest solution to this, if that's an option. Just loop through each inner element and position it accordingly. If you provide some of your code I can help you out more.

Comment: @Evilzebra, thanks for responding. I'm hoping for a pure CSS solution, but it would be nice to have Javascript as a backup option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428738/how-to-center-text-in-table-cell-when-it-overflow/26428969

Comment: @trnelson, thanks for finding that. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26429137/184108) on that questions solved it for me. Please go ahead and close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ItfAc

You could do this manually or programmatically with negative margin-left.

The formula is pretty simple: you take the amount the child div overflows by, cut that in half, and then make the result the negative margin value. So, if you have a child div with a width of 140%, margin-left: -20%.

If you want to avoid JS, this is pretty easy to do with Sass, e.g.:

```
@mixin width-overflow($width){
    width: percentage($width/100);
@if ($width > 100) {
    margin-left: -(percentage(($width - 100) * .005));
    }
}

.child-1 {
    @include width-overflow(140);
}
```

(The *.005 is just / 2 / 100 -- dividing the number by 100 just to convert it back into a percentage is kinda messy, but works. I'm sure there are more elegant ways than this.)